# JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery: Динамическое обновление контента

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Ситуация следующая: есть страничка на php поднятая на Apache, есть база данных на MySQL, на страничке имеется форма для отправления сообщений и обновление списка сообщений после отправки. Обновление сделал через AJAX, так же, на страничке стоит такой таймер:

```
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#refresh").load(location.href+" #refresh>*","");
  }, 2000);
```

Он каждые 2 секунды обновляет содержания div'a с id refresh, выводя сообщения из базы. Проблема в том, что он это делает даже если новые сообщения не появились в базе. Как можно сделать проверку на то, соответствует ли старое содержание, которое вернул сервер, новому, которое вернет сервер?
Скажу еще немного иначе. Как можно сделать обновление div'a refresh у каждого пользователя на странице, когда хоть один из них отправит сообщение?

Comment: Используйте jQuery.ajax вместо jQuery.fn.load, так как там вы сможете заменять html в ручную в зависимости от условий.

Comment: Чуть подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com - чуть подробнее здесь.